# hibernate reverse engineering on a denormalized database

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jdbc, pojo

is it possible to use reverse engineering on a denormalized database? hibernate reverse engineering to generate the Pojo classes for all the tables in the database didnt seem to work because none of the tables have any primary keys or foreign keys in them. what is the solution to this?

i did it using Netbeans & the error was that Pojo classes cant be generated because the tables do not have primary keys.

Comment: this question might be helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8563437/1065180

Comment: what if the table doesn't have a primary key constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the primary/foreign keys in the database befor using the tool. Maybe in a clone of the original database. Other than that you can only write the mapping yourself.

Comment: the application is to be built for a legacy database. and the access granted is read-only. can i use any other tools (like JOOQ, MiddleGen ?)

Comment: can't you make a copy of the database, create the constraints there and generate it from there. The original won't be touched.

Comment: no. cloning the database is not an option. (actually, there are multiple schemas with the same datamodel.It is not just one. And the datasource is to be identified in a dynamic way). I am thinking about creating the POJO classes manually and using JDBC for the queries (since using ORm tools doesnt look like a great idea for this scenario). Do you have any other ideas in mind? Is there a way we can specify the relations just in Hibernate without disturbing the databases?

Comment: What makes you think an ORM is not good in this scenario? Missing constraints are no problem for an ORM, my last 2 projects were legacy dbs without constraints, the ORM doesn't care. It's only relevant when you let hibernate create the schema and then you can disable creation of constraints.  The database clone is only there to reverse engineer once then you can build up from there and throw away the clone. Or you just handwrite the mapping.

Comment: wow. It worked. I created Pojos manually and used the "@Entity" annotation (with out using "@Id" annotation). Then, I got an error "No identifier specified for entity". Then, I used "@Id" annotation to the first variable in the model classes (didnt even notice what they are). The application worked fine. Is it ok to go down this road? Is it going to create any problems when I write complex HQL queries?

Comment: this is the normal way, writing mappings/annotations by hand. Keep in mind that the mappings often contain much more information than the db schema. `@Id` should be on the property which **is** the id which is not nessessarily the first property. I strongly suggest you read a beginners guide to hibernate mapping/annotations

Comment: That is the problem. The tables do not have any Ids. Which element should be marked @Id? Can we even use Hibernate(ORM) here?

Comment: one or more columns together that are unique over all possible rows are the primaryKey/Id