# How to generate POJO classes from legacy db tables that doesn't have primary key

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to create a pojo classes base on some legacy tables which apparently doesn't have a unique key assigned to them (meaning some tables don't even have a primary key or a unique value).

With that being said, which apporach should I take to generate my pojo classes in java? Any suggestions? 
As well, which model should I be going for in this case, Hibernate or myBatis?

What if there is one to many relationships? Do I have to manually generate those pojo myself?

Comment: Your ORM doesn't really care of the table actually has a primary key or unique constraints, but you may run into problems if data in the table effectively isn't unique. ie. you can pick the column (or columns) which "will be" unique, but does the DB contain duplicates?

Comment: I worked on a project once where I was told "don't add rows to this table where this column value already exists". I asked, "why isn't there a constraint on that then?". The answer, "because there are already duplicates in there". :/

Comment: Yes, there is a chance that there will be duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the hibernate configuration tools to help me generate those entity classes. For tables that doesn't have a primary key, the hibernate configuration tools will generate one extra class to store a value called ID (for mapping purposes), and I might have to manually delete those classes.

http://hibernate.org/tools/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hibernate as ORM tool and apply reverse engineering, ORM tool doesn't bother about constraint.

[hibernate reverse engineering on a denormalized database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346484/hibernate-reverse-engineering-on-a-denormalized-database)

Comment: So even without a primary key and unique key, this can still work? I thought Hibernate as ORM requires a unique value inside the table itself.

Comment: The ORM doesn't care. It's only relevant when you let hibernate create the schema and then you can disable creation of constraints.

Comment: @Vishwas you should copy the relevant part of your linked page to your answer.